# Confusion with limit absolute values

Tags: limits

I am kind of confused when it comes to working with absolute values in limit problems. When $x$ is approaching negative infinity and $\lvert x\rvert$ then we write $-x$. Why?

I am confused because when we have an absolute value and the whole expression is approaching some small negative value we don't do this? For example if x is approaching $-\frac{2}{3}$ from the left side and we have $\lvert 3x + 2\rvert$ we just write $0$. We don't note the negative sign in some way like in the first case.

Comment: Those are certainly all words

Comment: @paxtibimarce Hard to explain through examples in my opinion. I think it is easier to ask this way

Comment: What do you mean by 'if $x$ is approaching $-\frac{2}{3}$ from the left side ... which then means the result goes to positive infinity'? That does not quite make sense.

Comment: @iobtl What I meant is that the absolute value gets no minus in front of it like it does for the first case. I've edited my post

Comment: Note that $|3x+2|$ is a continuous function. So we can just substitute in the x value to get the limit. There's no need to remove the absolute value signs.

Comment: That is because we know that a function given by $f(x) = |3x + 2|$ is continuous at $x= -\frac{2}{3}$ and evaluates to $0$.

Comment: Think about it this way: even if you were to include the negative sign and evaluate $f\left(-\frac{2}{3}\right)$, what difference would there be?

Comment: And why do we add the negative sign when x is approaching negative infinity? @iobtl

Comment: What is the precise definition of the statement '$x$ is approaching negative infinity'?

Comment: Try to form meaningful sentences. For instance "we have $\lvert 3x + 2\rvert$ we just write $0$": what ?!?

Comment: @user737163 The fact that there is the "minus" sign does not mean that $-x$ is negative.

Answer (score 0):

When $x>0$,

$$|x|=x,$$

and when
$x<0$,

$$|x|=-x,$$

that's all.

Comment: In my high school teacher experience I've had hundreds of students who were convinced that $|x|$ is $x$ because they were taught in middle schools that "absolute value is the number without its sign". Not always it's kid's fault.

Comment: @Raffaele: would an example like $|-1|=-(-1)$ help or add confusion ?

Comment: When I teach this stuff I tell my students that absolute value is the distance of the number from the origin of the real line. Then I give the symbolic definition. Anyway it's hard to work with this function. Even seniors are convinced that $|x|=x$ and $|-y|=y$.

Comment: @Raffaele: would an example like $|−1|=−(−1)$ help or add confusion ? –

Comment: Add confusion don't use it

Comment: @Raffaele: ironically, it should be obvious that $|x|\ne x$, whatever $|x|$ might mean, otherwise the concept/notation would never have been introduced !